# IdentityServer4 token request with axios and react-native

Tags: react-native, axios, identityserver4

I'm trying to figure out what is wrong with my code to request an access token from IdentityServer4 API using my react-native android app with axios.

Whatever I do my server always responds with HTTP 400 error `invalid_grant`.

Below is the code of my method to request the data. I tried various ways to make a request (the ones I could find people discussing on SO and github) but all of them either give me `invalid_grant` or `invalid_client` error.

I'm pretty sure that the server itself is OK because I can do the same request using PostMan just fine.

I did inspection of the request in android emulator with the app running. It looks like the request body is OK and `'content-type'` header present and correct.

If someone knows what is happening here please help. I run out of ideas. All snippets and examples I could find online including official docs do not give me expected result.

Here's the code of my method

```
import axios from 'axios';
import qs from 'qs';

const API_CLIENT_ID = 'ro.client';
const API_CLIENT_SECRET = 'secret';
const API_BASE_URL = "http://localhost:5002";    

async getAccessToken(credentials) {
    const axiosConfig = {
        baseURL: API_BASE_URL,
        timeout: 30000,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        }
    };

    const requestData = {
        client_id: API_CLIENT_ID,
        client_secret: API_CLIENT_SECRET,
        grant_type: 'password',
        username: credentials.username,
        password: credentials.password,
        scope: 'api1'
    };

    try {
        const result = await axios.post('/connect/token', qs.stringify(requestData), axiosConfig);           
        return result.response;
    } catch (err) {
        return err;
    }       
}
```

Below is the screenshot from postman with successful result using the same request parameters.

[Screenshot from postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0t1H.jpg)

Comment: I tried to use fetch instead of axios but got the same error...

Comment: Are you able to look into the server logs? It should give more information about why it's issuing `invalid_grant`.

Comment: @KirkLarkin thank you for giving me a hint how to find a source of error. I added it as an answer.

Comment: Hello @PeterRogov, shouldn't it be using Implicit grant flow from React Native? I found a library that might help if you choose to go that route. https://github.com/FormidableLabs/react-native-app-auth

Comment: @AnupMarwadi thanks for the hint. I actually thought about implicit flow but wasn’t sure about the proper way of implementing it on the mobile device. I will certainly give this one a try.

Comment: @PeterRogov damn I've the exact same problem. Tried firstly with fetch, then with axios without success, and the stranger thing is that in postman on windows the same exact request seems to work...

Comment: @GiacomoCerquone yes, so you should be very careful with the request and all its properties. If there’s an error you will only get “invalid_grant” with no further explanation. It also helps to read server logs since they are quite verbose in debug mode and can give you a good hint on what exactly is going wrong.

Comment: @PeterRogov thank you very much for the fast answer! I discovered it's a server problem, we're doing a request a little bit different than yours (the code->token exchange request) and there is a problem with the code!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the comment from Kirk Larkin I realized that my code was supplying empty username and password to server in request. Instead of giving any meaningful response server just sends `invalid_grant`.

Once I provided correct username and password the above code worked just fine.

Perhaps this will help someone.

Comment: Glad to help. It's somewhat of an obscure message but I guess there's a balance between helpful errors and giving away too much information.